# Bash echo color as function output in PS1

Tags: macos, bash, git, ps1

I want my PS1 to display (if i'm in a git folder) the branch, and color the branch with red if working dir is dirty, and blue if it's clean. Here is what i came up to

```
IBlack='\e[0;90m'       # Nero
IRed='\e[0;91m'         # Rosso
IGreen='\e[0;92m'       # Verde
IYellow='\e[0;93m'      # Giallo
IBlue='\e[0;94m'        # Blu
IPurple='\e[0;95m'      # Viola
ICyan='\e[0;96m'        # Ciano
IWhite='\e[0;97m'       # Bianco

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
branch_color() {
    if git status | grep --quiet "nothing to commit"; then
        echo -e "$IBlue"
    else
        echo -e "$IRed"

    fi
}


PS1="\[$IGreen\]\u \[$ICyan\][\W]\[\$(branch_color)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$IWhite\] \n → "
```

Now, the code prints this:

```
francesco [demo_app]\e[0;94m (master) 
→
```

where **francesco** is my user name, **demo_app** is the folder and **master** is the branch. the sequence **\e[0;94m** changes if I create a file in the working dir, but the color doesn't get parsed as you can see.

Then I tried to change the PS1 like this:

```
PS1="\[$IGreen\]\u \[$ICyan\][\W]\[$(branch_color)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$IWhite\] \n → "
```

removing the '\' before (branch_color), and now it parses the color but it doesn't change when the working dir status change.

How can I solve this? Sorry if I was not clear.

Francesco

Comment: Ouch, sorry, brain bug, I shouldn't answer questions so late... I deleted my answer since it was indeed exactly the same but the `\e[0;94m (master)` was probably because of a syntax error, copy pasting your exact code works fine on my system.

Comment: Which is your system? because on mine still doesn't work. it outputs the color as a string in the prompt instead of parsing it (i am on OSX 10.9.1)

Comment: Ah, I'm on Linux. It might be a difference in `echo` implementation, `printf` tends to be [safer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222). Try replacing the two echo calls in `branch_color()` with `printf "\e[0;94m"` and `printf "\e[0;91m"`

Comment: Maaan that worked! thank you! (post it as an answer so I can assign it)

Comment: Great! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have works perfectly on my Debian. Your problem might be that OSX's `echo` is not printing the escape sequence correctly.

It is generally better to avoid `echo` and use `printf` instead since different systems have different `echo` implementations and that can affect the portability of your scripts and cause other issues as well. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) for (much) more details.

Anyway, try replacing the `echo`s in your function with `printf:

```
branch_color() {
    if git status 2>/dev/null | grep --quiet "nothing to commit"; then
        printf "\e[0;94m"
    else
        printf "\e[0;91m"

    fi
}
PS1="\[$IGreen\]\u \[$ICyan\][\W]\[\$(branch_color)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$IWhite\] \n → "



PS1="\[$IGreen\]\u \[$ICyan\][\W]\[\$(branch_color)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$IWhite\] \n → "
```

Comment: Great,  selected the answer,  ty